# MySQL - Prevent Insertion of Record if ID and Timestamp Unique Combo Constraint Within Timeframe

Tags: mysql, datetime, constraints, unique

I have a scenario in which 3 standalone agents are reporting uptime statuses for various hosts.  If the hosts go down and are offline, a downtime record should be created.  Unfortunately, since the agents report exactly at the same time with the same information, I've seen duplicate entries that are 1-2 seconds apart.

I have a unique constraint that was created on the table for both the datetime and the host ID.  Thus, they cannot be the same.  But if the requests from the agents come in at the same time or a second apart, a duplicate might be created despite code checks looking for an existing entry (in this case, an entry hasn't been created yet in all three instances if the agents report at the same time).  The unique constraint won't prevent the duplicates either, since the datetime might be 1 second ahead or behind when the PHP / MySQL call finishes getting processed...

So, what is the best way to handle this situation?  Is there a way in MySQL to specify that if a unique constraint (which includes a datetime field) is within a certain time frame of another record with the unique constraint, it shouldn't be allowed to insert?

Do I need to run a job that removes entries within a few seconds of each other, or is there a way to get MySQL to do this for me somehow?

Table structure looks like this

entry_id host_id datetime

Entries might be

1      121     01/17/2019 02:38:04 AM

**1      121     01/17/2019 02:38:05 AM**

1      121     01/17/2019 02:36:04 AM

I want to prevent the insertion of the bold entry since it's within 1 second from the last entry that was inserted.  Code checks won't work because no entries may exist at the time it checks for one.  I already have a code check looking for an existing entry, and since it doesn't find one and the code can be run at the same time for each request, the check fails and says a new entry should be created.

There are more datetime columns in my table, but they aren't needed to understand this situation.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See about the importance of using proper data types

Comment: And once you've fixed that, as an alternative to Barmar's suggestion, you can just bind the logic into the INSERT itself

Comment: @Strawberry, not sure what you mean.  I am using a proper data type.

Comment: OK - but 01/17/2019 doesn't look like one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 5.7 or newer, you can define a generated column that contains the timestamp rounded down to a 5 or 10 second range. Then you can define a unique index on that column, so you'll get a constraint violation if you try to create two records with timestamps in that same period.

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable 
ADD datetime_10sec INT AS (10 * ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/10)) PERSISTENT, 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (host_id, datetime_10sec);
```

Change both `10` to whatever time granularity you want to use.

Comment: Do you know if this works with MariaDB?  I can't seem to get it to work with version 5.5 or 10.0.36.  This seems like the right solution to my problem though if I can get it to work.  I appreciate your help and thank you for this idea!

Comment: It was added in MySQL 5.7, that's why it doesn't work with 5.6.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/ says: Virtual columns first appeared in MariaDB 5.2. Several limitations in them were lifted in MariaDB 10.2.1.

Comment: More: before 10.2.3 only PERSISTENT virtual columns could be indexed.

Comment: Maybe I should upgrade to a  version greater than 10.2.1 then because when I try to run it in 10.0.36, I get the following: ALTER TABLE downtime 
ADD datetime_10sec AS (10 * ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/10))

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS (10 * ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/10))' at line 2

Comment: Or you can make it a persistent column.

Comment: Generated columns are virtual by default.

Comment: Hmm, still can't get it work when using this query:  ALTER TABLE downtime 
ADD datetime_10sec AS(10 * ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/10)) STORED;  Any idea?

Comment: I left out the datatype `INT` before `AS`. Try now.

Comment: Use `PERSISTENT` keyword instead of `STORED` before 10.2.1.

Comment: Thanks, that changed my error message to "#1901 - Function or expression is not allowed for column 'datetime_10sec'" on MariaDB 10.0.36 despite using `PERSISTENT` instead of `STORED` and adding `INT` before `AS` in the previous alter query I posted, so I'm wondering if I still need to upgrade MariaDB

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to that version of MariaDB, so I can't try things myself. I tested on dbfiddle.uk, it just has 10.2 and 10.3.

Comment: So maybe upgrading will be necessary.

Comment: Upgraded to 10.2.20, and now I get:  #1054 - Unknown column 'DATETIME' in 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS'

Comment: Nvm, I see that needs to be the column name that references the original datetime.  Got it!

Comment: I guess my only possible concern that remains is what will I do after 2038 since UNIX_TIMESTAMP can't store ints larger than that date... but I guess that's something MySQL or MariaDB will handle in the future???  I mean, most of us are running 64bit now.  Looking too far ahead, but it's only in 19 years.

Comment: You could use `BIGINT` instead of `INT`, and hope that sometime in the next 19 years the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is changed to return `BIGINT`.